# Set onTouchListener to Bitmap image?

Tags: java, android

What I am trying to do is when someone touches my bitmap image, something happens. I've been having a hard time trying to find out what to do. I have a canvas and a bitmap drawn on it. How do I get it so where if you touch the image, something happens. Here's the code I have so far:

Drawing class for drawing the canvas and bitmap

```
package com.example.touchperson;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class Drawing extends View {

    Bitmap robot; 
    //Ignore this float x, y;
    public Drawing(Context context)  {
        super(context);
         robot = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources()    , R.drawable.character);


        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(robot, 200, 200,  null);
    //}

}
}
```

Here's the main activity class

```
package com.example.touchperson;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {


    Drawing view;
    int touchCount = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        view = new Drawing(this);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);
        setContentView(view);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        return false;
    }




}
```

Here's the xml file. But I believe this is useless since I did it programmaticly.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

At first i tried using the method MotionEvent.getX && MotionEvent.getY == 200, then do something since I have my image is set to (200,200) but that didn't work. (Those methods are in the API.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `setOnClickListener` instead. That way the `View` will handle all the touch events by default, triggering your listener only when a click event was detected.

Comment: you can set a onclicklistener to a bitmap?

Comment: @recheej: No, you cannot. But you can set a `OnClickListener` to the `Drawing` `View` that holds your `Bitmap`

Comment: so how do i get it to do something specific to the bitmap and not the whole view?

Comment: @recheej: Make the whole view wrap its content, and that would be just the bitmap.. or are you trying to ignore clicks on transparent areas?

Comment: It's a canvas with a bitmap on it.

Comment: https://rmnxga.bn1.livefilestore.com/y1pwIXkYlLkXUoG40RrpqaLrxrP2wQjjAffdxeCR6J8qVIGjHI4hYRfIxVkrTLMv0lRO8yf4_Xa08Qj8ppb30IgkxF4xlQ7ncLq/Screenshot_2012-12-23-19-14-18.png?psid=1